# L-C Circuit (Series) connected with AC power

Tags: resonance

Good morning
I am learning about L-C circuits, because it is very interesting, so in my simulation software I built the circuit, which can be seen in the below image.

[image]

Why, and how i build it ?

I wanted to see in action, the reaction of L and C, resistance, while i increase and decrease the frequency. I know that, in low frequencies, the Capacitor's resistance, increase, and the Coil's resistance decrease (and vise versa), and in resonance these two, are equal, so the Volts value of these two, became opposites and cancel each other, and this means, if i understand well, that there is no Volts against the Volts of the source, so the circuit acts like a close, one.(in a series connection between L and C)

I calculated the frequency of the source, in order to be resonance between L and C, and i found must be 79.577 Hz. When I, first, connected the oscilloscope,  the V(L) and V(C), were both, increasing (while they execute their cycles), with no end.

So  adding resistance, between L an C, and this, stopped this increase and hold Volts stable. After that, Volts(of L) and Volts(of C) had opposite phases and equal values, as expected. But when I tried to measure, Volts, at the ends of Coil(L) and at the ends of the Capacitor(C), I received these indications : 119.964 Volts with only 12V applied.

My questions are:

1. Why before i insert the resistor in the circuit, the L and C volts, were increasing continuously ?
2. Why the resistor, stable the Volt sinusoidal movement ?
3. Why Volts in the ends of L and C are 119 Volts ? The Vrms of the source is 12, and as far as i know the relationship between Vrms and Vpeak is Vrms=0.707Vpk, thus the Vpk should be 16.97 Volt.

I need to know what is happening, in general, because this relation between L and C it is a kind of magic, to me. I mean, i am fascinated.
Is there a good tutorial, to understand?

Comment: Calculate the Q of that circuit.

Comment: false assumption: a) Input is RMS, Meter is RMS for sine (averaged) although some meters measure peak, some average but convert to RMS by 0.707 giving false readings for pulses or too low if using average and too high if using peak detection.

Comment: [Similar question on resonance in LC circuits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/292147/lc-low-pass-filter-intuitive-understanding)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tutorials on RLC 
Basically you are amplifying applied voltage into stored voltage or energy ( that cannot be used with out reducing the energy and Q)

It is just like having pinging a tuning fork that oscillates forever without loss until you add resistance.

\$\omega=2\pi f=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$  and

Q= voltage gain = impedance gain since they all share the same current in series.
Let me use Qs for series and Qp for parallel RLC

\$Qs=\dfrac{X_L}{R}=\dfrac{X_C}{R}\$ at resonance frequency f where Xc=XL

For parallel;   it is just the inverse.
\$Qp=R/X\$ at resonance f

Now I leave it up to your research to know what is X(f) impedance is for L and C as well as the stored energy if it could be applied to some load. This is useful for some applications like RF tuners to get voltage gain by impedance ratios.

Can you find the intersection of 3 variables to get Q and f. So with these variables you can change it by sliding along the line to find the intercept and X/R is your Q.

If your meter reads in reads 120V in rms and you applied 12V rms then you measured a gain of 10.
[image]